# Converting an ADT(Advantage) Table within Advantange Data Architect to a CSV

Tags: csv, converters, load-testing, advantage-database-server

Currently, I am having the issue of converting a ADT database file to a CSV.

It seems to error out with saying that there is written permissions, and space issues.

This is not the case at all, and I have made sure neither one of these issues would be a concern.

It seems to export up to around 4500 rows, and then stops and presents the error above. What would be the best method to get around such an error?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 2):

The error was due to previously deleted rows/records not being fully removed from the ADT database.
[Description as per Why](https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage9.1/adt_deleted_records.htm)
Since then, pulling from ADT database's have become a regular occurrence. So I've switched over to using the ADSConnection libraries. This allows me to make a direct connection to the ADT DB and select statements by default do not include deleted rows.